# Can we make the standard "Close Date" field non mandatory on opportunity or remove it from opportunity page layout?

Tags: page-layout, configuration, required-field, standard-field

I don't want "Closed Date" field on Opportunity layout but I am not able to remove it from page layout as it is standard field and required field on opportunity is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The standard "Close Date" field cannot be removed from any page layout for the Opportunity object, nor can the "Required" property be removed.

Refer to this document for more information: ([Remove the required 'Close Date' field on an Opportunity page layout](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385013&type=1))

Answer (score 0):

Removing required fields from the detail page is possible via Dynamic forms on the record page.

We need to remove the existing detail page and add the fields one by one as we wish to show. When we save it'll show the warning stating that the required field is not added on the page; however, it'll not block the user. Plus with dynamic form we can show/hide the fields/buttons based on conditions.